# ios - sendSubviewToBack and bringSubviewToFront causes subviews of root view controller to move up and be overlapped by navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a problem with sendSubviewToBack and bringSubviewToFront calls. I create UIImageView and ScrollView with several other elements (like buttons and labels) programmaticaly (only ScrollView is created in storyboard). UIImageView have to hold a background image. ScrollView and UIImageView are added as subviews of view controller (other elements are subviews of scrollview). After I create a UIImageView and set the image like this, I call

```
self.backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chooseDoctorBackground"]];
[self.view addSubview:self.backgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundImage];
```

After that, scroll view "moves up" and becomes overlapped by navigation bar (it doesn't happening if we won't call sendSubviewToFront). There is an easy workaround - just to define position of UIImageView and UIScrollView explicitly (using setFrame) with consideration of navigation bar and status bar height. However, I don't understand the root cause of such behavior. Could you please explain it to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came here looking for help with a similar issue, and have since figured out the cause of both our problems:

When a UIScrollView is the back-most subview of your view, iOS will auto-pad the UIScrollView's content to account for the status bar and navigation bar. That is why your scroll view's content appears fine at first.

When you call

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.backgroundImage];
```

your UIImageView becomes the back-most subview, and the UIScrollView ceases to get auto-padded. That's why the content of the UIScrollView moves up underneath the navigation bar.

You'll need to manually set your scroll view's frame or content offset to account for the status and navigation bars in order to support the background view appearing behind.

(In my experience, this auto-pad behavior on UIScrollView happens even if the y origin of the scroll view is non-zero and it sits lower on the screen, nowhere near the status or navigation bars.)